# Effective way to calc without float, C

Tags: c, integer, integer-math

I need to do a math to convert a 16-bit value received from sensor to real relative humidity value. It's calculated with following formula:

[image: formula rh=-6+125*(Srh/2^16)]

Given this in floating point math that would be:

```
uint16_t buf = 0x7C80; // Example
float rh = ((float)buf*125 / 65536)-6;
```

But I want to avoid floating point math as my platform are "FPUless".

What are the most effective way to calculate & store RH in integer math here? Considering it's humidity the actual value should be between 0 and 100% but sometimes approximation could lead that rh could be slightly less than 0 or higher than 100 (if I would leave that float, I could just do something like `if (rh<0) rh=0; else if (rh>100) rh=100;`) and I care only about last 2 digits after decimal point (%.2f).

Currently I've solved this like this:

```
int16_t rhint = ((uint32_t)buf*12500 / 65536)-600;
```

And working with `rhint / 100; rhint % 100`. But probably there are more effective way?

Comment: Whats wrong with current implementation (If the care is taken that `rhint` is divided by 100 or whatever is scaled to)?

Comment: @WedaPashi, I don't like it works with 32-bit value to multiply it only to divide it back to 16-bit boundaries. I think there are might be a better solution probably using only 2x 8-bit variables achieved with div&mod.

Comment: What is the maximum value that you can read from the sensor? Is it 0xFFFF?

Comment: @jwdonahue 0xFFF0 theoretically as it's 12-bit value actually.

Comment: Is a 32 bits CPU or a 16 bits ? If it's a 32 bits CPU, your solution is fine. But you could also simply do that `rhint = ((uint32_t)buf*125 - 65536 * 6`

Comment: But practially as we speaking of % value, which can't go above 100 it's somewhere around 0xD9F0.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the large intermediate term by writing the right hand side as

```
-6 + (128 - 4 + 1) * S / 65536
```

Which becomes

```
-6 + S / 512 - S / 16384 + S / 65536
```

You might be able to drop the last term, and possibly the penultimate one too depending on how precise you want the basis point truncation to be.

Comment: S is a 12 bits number, this is not going to work, you are going to lose a lot of precision

Comment: If we simply your code since we know the S range, we get that: `-6 + S / 512`